# How to close Flutter dialog from outside

Tags: flutter, dart

This is how we close a dialog from **INSIDE**

```
 showSomeDialog() {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext contextPopup) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Center(
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(contextPopup).pop();
                },
                child: Text('Close me inside'),
              ),
            ),);
        }
    );
  }
```

How to close this dialog from **OUTSIDE** ? In other words, how does the stateful widget creating this dialog can access the variable `contextPopup` ?   The problem with `Navigator.of(context).pop()` is that it will close the topmost widget on the Navigation stack, not this specific dialog.

In Android, to close a dialog programmatically from **outside**, you just do:

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: You can create a function(in the stateful widget) with a `context` as parameter and call the function in the onPressed of the `Dialog` by passing the `contextPopup` to it's param.

Comment: The goal is to close it programmatically outside of the dialog. The button you are referring to is inside of the dialog